# EF error: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor and working in a server-side Blazor app (.NET 5) have the following:

I have the following form:

```
 <EditForm Model="@MyObject" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
      <DataAnnotationsValidator />
      <ValidationSummary />

     <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="MyObject.Name" />

     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
```

Code behind:

```
public MyObject MyObject { get; set; } = new MyObject();
    
[Inject]
private IMyObjectService myObjectService { get; set; }

[Inject]
private NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; }

void Submit()
{
    var created = myObjectService.CreateMyObject(MyObject);

    if (created != null)
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("myobjects/manage");
    } else
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Repo:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

public MyObjectRepo(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
   _dbContext = dbContext;
}

public async Task<MyObject> CreateMyObject(MyObject MyObject)
{
   _dbContext.Add(MyObject);
   await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   return MyObject;
}

public async Task<bool> DoesMyObjectExistByName(string name)
{
    var exists = await _dbContext.MyObjects.AnyAsync(x => x.Name == name);

    if (exists) return true;
    return false;
}
```

I then have a `MyObjectService`:

```
private readonly IMyObjectRepo _myObjectRepo ;
        
public MyObjectService(IMyObjectRepo myObjectRepo  )
{
    _myObjectRepo  = myObjectRepo;
}

public async Task<MyObject> CreateMyObject(MyObject MyObject)
{
   if (MyObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("MyObject cannot be null.");

   // THIS LINE THROWS THE EF ERROR
   var exists = await _myObjectRepo.DoesMyObjectExistByName(MyObject.Name);

   if (!exists)
   {
      return await _myObjectRepo.CreateMyObject(MyObject);
   } else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

But every time I call the service to createMyObject method, EF throws an error:

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was
> started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is
> usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
> instance of DbContext.

In Startup.cs (.NET 5), I configure with a Transient lifetime.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")),
        ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
services.AddScoped<IMyObjectRepo, MyObjectRepo>();
services.AddScoped<IMyObjectService, MyObjectService>();
```

I think I'm using all the correct syntax for async/await and thread safety, any ideas?

Comment: please also include your codes of Razor pages or Controler (if you are using asp.net core mvc)

Comment: What's the lifetime of your service and repository?

Comment: Could you share the controller action method, and how you registered `MyObjectService' and `MyObjectRepo`?

Comment: updated original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Blazor` myself, but I think your `Submit` method should look like -

```
async void Submit()
{
    var created = await myObjectService.CreateMyObject(MyObject);

    if (created != null)
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("myobjects/manage");
    } else
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Basically, you are missing the async/await keywords.